# How to compare input with multiple string (an array of string) using strcmp()?

Tags: c, string, strcmp

This is my code so far

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>  

int main() {
    char size[10];
    const char drinks[4][10] = {
        "Coffee",
        "Tea",
        "Chocolate",
        "Soda"
    };
    const char sizes[3][10] = {
        "Small",
        "Medium",
        "Large"
    };
    char drinksName[10];
    do {
        printf("\nDrinks name: ");
        scanf("%s", drinksName);
        if (strcmp(drinksName, drinks[0]) != 0 || strcmp(drinksName, drinks[1]) != 0 || strcmp(drinksName, drinks[2]) != 0 || strcmp(drinksName, drinks[3]) != 0) {
            printf("Not available.");
        }
    } while (strcmp(drinksName, drinks[0]) != 0 || strcmp(drinksName, drinks[1]) != 0 || strcmp(drinksName, drinks[2]) != 0 || strcmp(drinksName, drinks[3]) != 0);
    do {
        printf("\nSize: ");
        scanf("%s", size);
        if (strcmp(size, sizes[0]) != 0 || strcmp(size, sizes[1]) != 0 || strcmp(size, sizes[2]) != 0) {
            printf("Not available.");
        }
    } while (strcmp(size, sizes[0]) != 0 || strcmp(size, sizes[1]) != 0 || strcmp(size, sizes[2]) != 0);
}
```

When I try to run my program, input always loop whereas my input is true, ex: "Coffee". Is there an error in my looping code?

```
do {
        printf("\nDrinks name: ");
        scanf("%s", drinksName);
        if (strcmp(drinksName, drinks[0]) != 0 || strcmp(drinksName, drinks[1]) != 0 || strcmp(drinksName, drinks[2]) != 0 || strcmp(drinksName, drinks[3]) != 0) {
            printf("Not available.");
        }
    } while (strcmp(drinksName, drinks[0]) != 0 || strcmp(drinksName, drinks[1]) != 0 || strcmp(drinksName, drinks[2]) != 0 || strcmp(drinksName, drinks[3]) != 0);
```

I'm confused why this happened.

Answer (score 0):

Your code means to continue the loop if your input is differ from *one of* the elements. This condition will always be true because there are different elements.

You should check if you input is differ from *all of* the elements by using `&&` (logical AND) operator instead of `||` (logical OR) operator like this:

```c
do {
    printf("\nDrinks name: ");
    if (scanf("%9s", drinksName) != 1) {
        fputs("Read error.\n", stderr);
        return 1;
    }
    if (strcmp(drinksName, drinks[0]) != 0 && strcmp(drinksName, drinks[1]) != 0 && strcmp(drinksName, drinks[2]) != 0 && strcmp(drinksName, drinks[3]) != 0) {
        printf("Not available.");
    }
} while (strcmp(drinksName, drinks[0]) != 0 && strcmp(drinksName, drinks[1]) != 0 && strcmp(drinksName, drinks[2]) != 0 && strcmp(drinksName, drinks[3]) != 0);
```

Also note that you should specify the maximum length of string to read to avoid buffer overrun and check the return value of `scanf()` to check if reading succeeded.

Another option is using a loop to find a matching element like this:

```c
int matchFound;
do {
    printf("\nDrinks name: ");
    if (scanf("%9s", drinksName) != 1) {
        fputs("Read error.\n", stderr);
        return 1;
    }
    matchFound = 0;
    for (size_t i = 0; i < sizeof(drinks) / sizeof(drinks[0]); i++) {
        if (strcmp(drinksName, drinks[i]) == 0) {
            matchFound = 1;
            break;
        }
    }
    if (!matchFound) {
        printf("Not available.");
    }
} while (!matchFound);
```